# converting from size_t to unsigned int

Tags: c++, type-conversion, unsigned-integer

Is it possible that converting from size_t to unsigned int  result in overflow .

```
 size_t x  = foo ( ) ;  // foo ( ) returns a value in type size_t
 unsigned int ux = (unsigned int ) x ;

 ux == x  // Is result of that line always 1 ?
```

language : c++

platform : any

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible, `size_t` and `int` don't necessarily have the same size. It's actually very common to have 64bit `size_t`s and 32bit `int`s.

C++11 draft N3290 says this in §18.2/6:

> The type **size_t** is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

`unsigned int` on the other hand is only required to be able to store values from 0 to `UINT_MAX` (defined in `<climits>` and following the C standard header `<limits.h>`) which is only guaranteed to be at least 65535 (2<sup>16</sup>-1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, overflow can occur on some platforms. For example, `size_t` can be defined as `unsigned long`, which can easily be bigger than `unsigned int`.